# how to check nginx is serving static file or not

Tags: node.js, nginx, server

This is my nginx.conf file.  i want to serve all static contents that are located in different directories.

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    server {
      listen       8080;
      server_name  localhost;


      location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            access_log C:/Program Files/nginx-1.11.7/logs/access.log;
      }

      location ~* \.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|html)$ {
        root D:/gamma-master;
            autoindex on;
            access_log C:/Program Files/nginx-1.11.7/logs/access.log;

      }

    }


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```

How to check nginx is serving static file or not. Also how should give static file path if my static content is located in different folders under root folder

Comment: If you are just looking for confirmation, you could change the access log for the `location` block that serves your static files.

Comment: yes but how i will come to know its serving statically by Nginx or server is serving

Comment: is there any way to check this ?

Comment: Which server, you mean on port 3000? If you have one access log for `location /` and one access log for `location ~* \.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|html)`, if the request is in the first log, the request was proxied, and if the second it wasn't.

Comment: see my server is running on port 3000  this is url - localhost:3000. suppose i have 2 folders img and css inside D:/gamma-master . then i added above code in config for sending my images and css file statically using nginx                                                                       (location ~* \.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|html)$ {
        root D:/gamma-master;
            autoindex on;
            access_log C:/Program Files/nginx-1.11.7/logs/access.log;

      }